# Reserve the App Market URL in advance

Tags: android, url, google-play

We are currently developing an android app for our client. Client would like to include a barcode on a it’s mailing about the Android app, such that when the user scans the barcode, s/he will be taken directly to the application on the Android marketplace for download. To do this, client will need to know the exact URL on the marketplace, but we are not sure if a URL can be reserved in advance of actually putting the app on the market

Answer (score 7):

The URL is composed of the application's namespace. The way to do it would be to put together any sort of app with the namespace (com.thecompany.theapp) and get it uploaded. You don't necessarily need to make it available to the public yet by publishing it, but getting it uploaded should claim the space, and you'll know what the URL will be when it is ready.

With that, as long as the combination of the company name and application name are reasonably unique, there's really no reason to worry that someone else would pop up with the same namespace and take it out from under you, so reserving is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to redirect the user to a URL of your own and manage the redirections from your own server. That way, if the url of your application changes it should be really easy to change it without bothering the users.